# Prove that the composition of two "closed form functions" is itself a "closed form function"?

Tags: functions, closed-form, function-and-relation-composition

So I have been given the definition of a "closed form function" that is a set of functions built inductively (mapping from and to the complex) starting with the fact that the constant functions $0(x)=0$ and $1(x)=1$ for all $x$ belong to our set, and then the rest is found inductively by saying that the set is closed under addition, multiplication, the negative of a function belongs to our set. Our set is also closed under exponentiation and if our functions isn't equal to $0$, an inverse exists and our set is closed under taking logarithm (principal branch).

I have been given the task to show that the composition of any two "closed form functions" is still a closed form function. Any hints on how I could go about proving this.

Comment: Is it not enough to recognize that the requirements of closure under the given operations imply that the range of either function must be contained in the domain of the other function? Honest question, I am naive to some of the terminology used herein, but it seems like the standard approach. Or... by "out set" did you mean to type "our set", in which case I know exactly what you're talking about.

Comment: It seems that you don't even have the identity function in your repository? Then all your functions are constant, hence for composition we have $f\circ g=f$.